# PHP cache script returns broken image

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to cache an users look from an external website and cache it locally in the same folder.
I've come up with this so far:

```
    <?php
  $figure = $_GET['figure'];
    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $direction = $_GET['direction'];
    $head_direction = $_GET['head_direction'];
    $gesture = $_GET['gesture'];
    $size = $_GET['size'];
    $imgFile = "$figure$action$direction$head_direction$gesture$size";
    $imagesPath =  $imgFile;

    if(!file_exists(($imagesPath))) {

        $otherSiteUrl  = "http://sourcewebsite.com/image/look?figure=$figure&action=$action&direction=$direction&head_direction=$head_direction&gesture=$gesture&size=$size";
        file_put_contents($imagesPath, file_get_contents($otherSiteUrl));
        }

 header("Content-Type: image/png");
        readfile($imagesPath);

    ?>
```

This worked for a while until today.
I am not sure why. It just returns a broken image icon.

Comment: What debugging methods have you tried so far? Does the `file_exists($imagesPath)` return true? Or is it requesting the image? If it's requesting the image, are you getting any content returned in the `file_get_contents`?

Comment: You might have run out of space, meaning you can't create a new image.

Comment: @Pudge601 I tried the CLI and logging so far, what other methodes are recommend

Comment: @Sami Dz Hamida I have enough space left on the harddisk (>800GB)

Comment: @user2460028, they're fine, important thing is, we need to know what output you're getting, and what's happening, if we're going to solve this. So as far as my previous questions go, what have you been able to determine?

Comment: @Pudge601 Unfortunately not much since images don't give such detailed logs as normal PHP scripts. At least, my server is not blocked from the other server since it doesn't return a 403 and my server returns 200 OK to my browser, which is weird since the image is broken.

Comment: Okay, before the line `if (!file_exists...`, type in `var_dump(file_exists($imagesPath));die();`, and then take the url to the PHP script with all the same url parameters as you were using before, and paste it into a new tab in your browser

Comment: @Pudge601 This returns `bool(false)`

Comment: Okay, then it is requesting the file from the server. Now, remove the `var_dump..` line you just put in, and on the line before `file_put_contents(...`, add this code `var_dump(file_get_contents($otherSiteUrl));die();`, and run it the same way as before

Comment: @Pudge601 Now it's returning very weird characters http://i.imgur.com/bfEAgNZ.png

Comment: Okay, that looks like it's getting the image then. The problem could be that the file is not being created on your filesystem, which could be a permission issue. Remove the code you just added, and on the line before `header(..`, put `var_dump(file_exists($imagesPath));die();` and test again

Comment: @Pudge601 This returns `bool(false)` again.

Comment: As I expected. The file is not being created, for one reason or another. I'll try to give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it may be necessary to specify a directory in which to save these image files, rather than the current directory of the script that's running. For example, you could save them in a subfolder for the images, so the images path would become;

```
$imagesPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/imageCache/' . $imgFile;
```

This would require you to create a directory called "imageCache" in the directory where your script is located.

Next, you should set the permissions on this directory to allow your script to write a file into it. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx for Windows, or http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html for unix (mac and linux).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a ton. I moved my wwwroot folder to a different partition and of course the CHMOD settings didn't move. I used CHMOD on my folder and the script worked again. Thank you once again!